# How to Refine this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

By this formula

$$
\frac{1}{2}\delta_{r}=\frac{2 \tau_{0} L_{e}^{2}(1+\eta)}{E_{f} d_{f}}+\sqrt{\frac{8 G_{d} L_{e}^{2}(1+\eta)}{E_{f} d_{f}}}
$$

get this

$$
L_{e}\left(\delta_{r}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\tau_{0} \delta_{r}+2 G_{d}\right) E_{f} d_{f}}{4 \tau_{0}^{2}(1+\eta)}}-\sqrt{\frac{G_{d} E_{f} d_{f}}{2 \tau_{0}^{2}(1+\eta)}}
$$

i use mathematica do:

```mathematica
Solve[(2 t le^2 (1 + n))/(ef df) + Sqrt[(8 Gd le^2 (1 + n))/(ef df)] == 
     1/2*deltar, le][[2]] // Simplify;
Refine[%, ef > 0 && df > 0]
```

get this

[image]

The result is not what I want, what should I do?

Comment: How about `sol = Solve[(2 t le^2 (1 + n))/(ef df) + 
     Sqrt[(8 Gd le^2 (1 + n))/(ef df)] == 1/2*deltar, le, Reals, 
   Assumptions -> ef > 0 && df > 0 && n > -1];FullSimplify[sol, 
 Assumptions -> ef > 0 && df > 0 && n > -1 && Gd >= 0]`?

Comment: It doesn't look good

Comment: How did you get your "expected" solution? I think it is wrong!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I use maple software also is not good,maybe this solution is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The achievement of such a relation often strongly depends on the limitations imposed on parameters. Are they (some of them) positive? You should specify this.
2. The expression you give in your question is NOT the solution to the equation. Indeed, this is your equation:

   ```
   eq = 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(G l^2 (1 + n))/(d e)] + (2 l^2 (1 + n) t)/(d e) == del/2
   ```

   And this is the solution you gave above:

   ```
   rule = l -> Sqrt[((t*del + 2 G) e*d)/(4*t^2*(1 + n))] - Sqrt[(G*e*d)/(2*t^2*(1 + n))]
   ```

   Then the following shows that substitution of the formula you gave above does not lead to identity:

   ```
   eq /. rule // Simplify[#, {d > 0, G > 0, n > 0, e > 0, t > 0, del > 0}] &

   (*  d e (-2 G + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[G (2 G + del t)]) == 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[d e G (1 + n)]
       Abs[-Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(d e G)/(1 + n)] + Sqrt[(d e (2 G + del t))/(1 + n)]]  *)
   ```

   Note that I used the assumptions that all parameters are positive:

   ```
   {d > 0, G > 0, n > 0, e > 0, t > 0, del > 0}
   ```

   If this is not the case, it can be the reason why the solution you gave does not work.
3. Further, with the same assumptions, a rather simple expression for the solution can be achieved:

   ```
   sl = Solve[eq, l][[2]] // Simplify[#, {d > 0, G > 0, n > 0, e > 0, t > 0, del > 0}] &

   (*  {l -> Sqrt[(d e (4 G + del t - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[G (2 G + del t)]))/(1 + n)]/(2 t)}  *)
   ```

Have fun!